# How to pass multiple parameters after the URL with /

Tags: servlets, path-parameter

I want to pass the parameters after the URL with using 'forward slash(/). For example:`{myURL.com}/{123}/{"test"}`. Here 'Name' and 'Id' are the parameters.

I know how to pass the parameters like `{myURL.com}?{Id=123}?{Name="test"}`.

Comment: what about if you concatenate that?

Comment: @KhalilM : not sure how to concatenate the parameters in the URL. do you have any sample code on this?

Comment: @BalusC :- This is not the exact duplicate question what you have mentioned. I want to implement based on the url parameters not mapped in the web.xml file. Hope you understand.

Comment: I found the solution in Spring MVC. If i use the @PathVariable i can pass the parameters in the url with /{id} and /{id}/{name}.

Answer (score -1):

To pass variables in the URL, start with `?` and separate each variable with `&`

```
myURL.com/servlet?name=cool&id=666&colour=blue
```